# Is there any way I can know who is behind a VPN?

Tags: vpn

As a website owner, is it possible to trace the real IP of the user of a VPN?

A VPN protects people but I can't imagine there isn't a way to find out who is actually behind a VPN, or am I wrong?

Comment: Ask them for their IP address!  </tongue-in-cheek>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you get the operator of the VPN to tell you, which may require a court order. Most (but not all) VPN operators keep those records.

Comment: But then, how do I find out who the operator of the VPN is?

Comment: You can find out who owns the IP address that's in your logs, for example by using whois.net's IP address lookup at http://tools.whois.net/whoisbyip/